# Delphi with Indy 10 - Best approach for TCP communication

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy

I am creating a client-server application using Delphi XE3 and Indy 10 (idTCPServer and idTCPClient).

Server side will show all connected clients, and I can select some clients on the list and send them commands or streams/files. For this I created a message queue, as sugested by Mr. Remy Lebeau. Here is what I am doing:

[image]

What I would like to know is:

1. Is this a good approach for what I am trying to do?
2. When one side starts read/writing, it expects other side to write/read? What if other side can't? Supose SERVER requests a file, but it doesn't exists, must CLIENT write an "empty" stream anyway to avoid problems?

BTW, I can't find any good example of this (Indy 10 TCP Communication), using queue, error handling, etc. On Indy's website there are many broken links. Can you sugest me a website with good examples?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the reason for not using an existing protocol (HTTP or WebSockets for example)

Comment: @mjn, I am new in this kind of programming. After some research, Indy and TCP seems to be the best tool and protocol for this. BTW, server and clients are on the same LAN...

Comment: OT: I'm still wondering why do people use strings for TCP remote commands. Why not just integers ? Do they afraid of the range `Low(Integer)..High(Integer)` or why is it so ? The only reason I can think of is readability, but that's what you (or potential attacker) don't necessarily need to have. Strings are harder to process on receiver's side and IMHO just a pure wasting of bandwidth. [I'm talking about commands, not their parameters]

Comment: @TLama, string command includes parameters like the path of the file to send. But maybe my knowledge about this topic was not enought for understanding your point...

Comment: @TLama Indeed, back when I first started, I created a TCP client/server wrapper (using ScktComp) with a pre-defined list of commands (in a TCollection). Although each possible command and parameter had a unique name, the actual transport used a unique ID - with encryption on top of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When one side starts read/writing, it expects other side to write/read? What if other side can't? Supose SERVER requests a file, but it doesn't exists, must CLIENT write an "empty" stream anyway to avoid problems?

Make the client send a reply accepting/rejecting the request before the file can then be transferred.  Also make the receiver send a reply after the transfer is finished so the sender knows whether the whole file was received or not on the receiver's end.

```
Server: I will send a file
Client: OK
Server: FileStream
Client: OK
```

```
Server: Send me a file
Client: OK
Client: FileStream
Server: OK
```

```
Server: I will send a file
Client: Not Ready
```

```
Server: Send me a file
Client: Not Found
```

```
Server: Send me a file
Client: OK
Client: FileStream (error midway)
Server: FAILED
```

With that said, since your server is the one sending commands to a client, consider using `TIdCmdTCPClient` on the client side instead of `TIdTCPClient`.  That will provide you with a dedicated thread to receive the server commands, and you can create `OnCommand` handlers for your commands and use the provided `TIdCommand` objects to send replies.

Consider using the `TIdTCPConnection.SendCmd()` method to send commands and read their initial responses, and `TIdTCPConnection.GetResponse()` to read the final responses.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Remy Lebeau, I will follow your tips! Btw, what if client also needs to send commands to server? Can I work with TIdCmdTCPServer and TIdCmdTCPClient ?

Comment: `TIdCmdTCPClient` and `TIdCmdTCPServer` do not work well together, as they are both designed as reading components, so they would deadlock/conflict with each other.  If you need to send commands in both directions, stick with `TIdTCPClient` and `TIdTCPServer`.  However, your protocol design does have a race condition you need to watch out for - what happens if the client and server send commands to each other at the *same time*? Make sure you design your protocol to account for that, by being able to differentiate between overlapping commands and responses, maybe by using framing/multiplexing.

Comment: Ok, thank you again! Please, let me know if there is some place where I can find some examples about this.

Comment: Hi Mr. Remy Lebeau. Sorry for opening this thread again, I can create a new one if needed. Well, do you think if I use a TIdCmdTCPClient (to receive the server commands) together with a TIdTCPClient (to send commands to server) would be a good solution to avoid issues with concurrent communication? Each one will work in a different port. Thanks!

Comment: Try not to use multiple ports if you can avoid it. That makes things harder for network/firewall admins to manage. Besides, you can use `TIdCmdTCPClient` to send commands, you would just have to design your protocol to be asynchronous (send a command, don't wait for the reply, process the reply separately when it arrives) and format the replies in such a way that the `CommandHandlers` can process. Since TCP is bidirectional, you can send outbound data using `TIdCmdTCPClient` at any time, but since it uses an internal reading thread, that thread will receive all inbound data.

Comment: Protocols that mix solicited (client commands to the server and their responses) and unsolicited data (server commands to the client at any time) are more difficult to implement in general, regardless of which component/library you use.  There are design issues to consider, and there are implementation details to consider.

Comment: Thank you again for the tips Mr. Remy Lebeau!!